# GeoMesa Accumulo for real time data

Tags: geoserver, real-time, geomesa

Is it possible to use GeoMesa Accumulo as a Geoserver Data store for real time data? i.e. Can Geoserver be configured to frequently read the data from Accumulo and update the layer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For such real time applications, it is more typical to use the GeoMesa Kafka DataStore.  This capability can maintain the most up-to-date information from a sensor or other updating entity.  Messages about the new information are passed via Kafka.

In GeoServer, the consumer maintains an in-memory database of the current state.  Since everything is in-memory, polling a GeoServer layer backed by a Kakfa DataStore is nice and quick.

For applications which require both historical and real time views, data can be written to both Accumulo (or HBase/C*) and Kafka.  The application can delegate historical requests to the bigger, distributed databases, and  current/live queries can be made against the Kafka DataStore.